# How can I use Ant Design with Next.js server-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, next.js13

I've been trying to figure out how I can use Ant Design ([antd](https://ant.design/)) in my next.js application. And it seems like I just can't do that. More precisely, I can, but then I just have to render everything on the client side, because almost every Ant Design component uses things that are not allowed for server-side components. Even the most simple things like `<Row>` and `<Col>`.

Comment: This question was closed falsely in my opinion. You'll find the answer to your question [here](https://mobile.ant.design/guide/ssr/#server-side-rendering--ssr).

Comment: @FabioNettis thanks a lot. I checked it. And it says I have to add 'use client' at the top of my files. It means I just can't avoid CSR, doesn't it? ))

Comment: Since client components can still receive server components as children, you're not completely dependent on client side rendering, ant-d seems to use context in it's components, henceforth the need for the `use-client` directive.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else stumbling upon this issue, based on the official [documentation](https://mobile.ant.design/guide/ssr) of Ant Design, you need to follow a few steps, based on the version of Next.js you are using.

---

##### Next.js 12

Using antd-mobile in Next.js requires some additional configuration. First, you need to install the `next-transpile-modules` package, then modify your `next.config.js`.

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'antd-mobile',
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  // other Next.js configuration in your project
});
```

##### Next.js 13

Next.js 13 can automatically transpile and bundle dependencies from external dependencies (node_modules). This replaces the `next-transpile-modules` package. Simply add this code to your `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  transpilePackages: ['antd-mobile'],
  // other Next.js configuration in your project
};
```

---

When using Next.js 13 you are required to add the 'use client' directive at the top of the file when using ant-d components inside it. Since client components can still receive server components as children, you're not completely dependent on client side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official docs for configuring ant design with Nextjs app router
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next

Comment: And of course, there will be limitations on using. Next.js App Router currently does not support using sub-components via "." and things like <Select.Option /> is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something like `ConfigProvider` without doing it like in the [docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next) (wrapping with theme), just create a component with `'use-client'` and wrap all its children:

```js
// src/component/theme-provider

"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";

export function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return (
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          token: {
            colorPrimary: "#f2f",
          },
          cssVar: true,
          hashed: false,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

Then wrap it in the main layout:

```js
// src/app/layout

import { AntdRegistry } from "@ant-design/nextjs-registry";
export default function MainLayout({ children, params: { locale } }: Props) {

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <AntdRegistry>
              <main>
                <div>{children}</div>
              </main>
            </AntdRegistry>
          </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```